# How to create vertical tabs in firefox addon?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Working on a firefox addon with a dialog box. I wish to create tabboxes with plenty of tabs in it. How can I make the tabs appear vertical [like this](http://11heavens.com/files/nodeFormVerticalTabs.jpg) ?
There doesn't seem to be any `orient` attributes for a [tabbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbox). Does it require some CSS hacking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself after 2 hours of painful search. For anyone looking for the answer, here it is :

- The tabbox container by default has a `vertical` orientation, so if we need to bring our tabs to the left, we need to make the `tabbox` orientation `horizontal` first. Although the Mozilla documentation for `tabbox` doesn't show `orient` attribute, it actually works. Optionally, you can set the style `-moz-box-orient:vertical`
- Now change the `tabs` orientation to `vertical`.

With both these settings, it should now work. Here is the example xul code :

```
<tabbox id="myTabList" selectedIndex="2" orient="horizontal">
  <tabs orient="vertical">
    <tab label="A First tab"/>
    <tab label="Second tab"/>
    <tab label="Another tab"/>
    <tab label="Last tab"/>
  </tabs>
  <tabpanels>
    <tabpanel><!-- tabpanel First elements go here --></tabpanel>
    <tabpanel><!-- tabpanel Second elements go here --></tabpanel>
    <tabpanel><button label="Click me"/></tabpanel>
    <tabpanel><!-- tabpanel Fourth elements go here --></tabpanel>
  </tabpanels>
</tabbox>
```

Although this works, it might result in poor rendering of the tabs as the tab edges are in the default direction. One may have to do some styling to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

you should have one tabbox with multiple tab elements.

do tabbox orient it vertical: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/orient

or just use a vbox. for horizontal orientation use hbox.

Comment: As already mentioned in the question, there is no `orient` attribute for a tabbox. Besides, merely using a vbox around the `tabs` or `tabpanel` elements doesn't make them vertical. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: my bad, there does seem to be `orient` for `tabbox`. Although the actual solution was bit tricky, and we need to change both `tabbox` and `tabs` elements.

Comment: can you please share your solution it will help others in future. edit: ah i see it thx for sharing